# Can I get cell-content from same row of reference cell, but different column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet of assets with unique identifiers. This sheet is named "Assets". The identifiers are in Column B.

Another sheet in the same workbook is named "Location".

If input a unique assets identifier in Location!E2, I want Location!H2 to check for a match in Column B on the "Assets"-sheet, then return with the value from the corresponding row, Column E. I also want Location!I to show "Assets!D (Assets!E)", and there are other columns I wish to show value from as well.

Is this possible without the use of VLOOKUP or INDIRECT?

Reason I don't want VLOOKUP is because I wish to be able to both filter and sort, and INDIRECT makes a big hassle if I re-organise the columns due to the complexity of other formulas in the workbook.

Both VLOOKUP and INDIRECT does give the basic functionality I'm looking for, but they are not ideal. What I'm currently doing is running a MATCH in column Location!F. This gives me the row-number. Then in Location!H I use INDIRECT.

I am currently using the following formulas:

- Location!F2: `=MATCH(E2,Assets!$B:$B,0)` (this finds the row-number)
- Location!H2: `=INDIRECT("'Assets'!G"&F2)` (this shows the value I want)

I'm hoping there's a better way to reach the same result, cause I don't want to have to remember to manually update every single "INDIRECT"-formula. Especially since I won't be the only one working on this sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still be able to use VLOOKUP without it messing up when sorted/filtered. You would just have to make sure you are using infinite bounds in your equations. For example:

- BAD: `VLOOKUP(A1, B1:C5, 2, 0)` This would likely fail when data was filtered out or rearranged by sorting.
- GOOD: `VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, 0)` This doesn't care about the bounds of your lookup, so it would still work, and I believe it will still examine cells being filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

If Vlookup doesn't work (and as Tyler mentioned .. I believe it "should") .. but if not, then this option may be what you're after ..

don't use INDIRECT, user OFFSET.

I have often used the combination of MATCH + OFFSET .. to "mimic" a VLOOKUP in more complex situations ..

so in H2 (on Location sheet) .. your formula would be something like this:

```
=MATCH(E2,Assets!B:B,0)
```

that gives you, effectively, the row # of the match (or an error if no match).
then in other columns, you can use that in the OFFSET function:

Let's say, in col I2, you can use the value returned by Match to:

```
=OFFSET(Assets!E1,I2-1,0,1,1)
```

which translates to:
Go to Assets sheet, cell E1.
Go down a number of rows equal to the value in cell I2 (minus 1).
(ie if value in I2 is 4, ie row "4" . we need to "go down" 3 rows from E1 .. to get to E4)
the next value "0" is column offset .. so 0 .. don't change columns.
and the 1,1 is the size of return set (yes, offset can return ranges .. handy for dynamic lists, etc.). In your case, just a single cell is all you want.

Then you can repeat that offset for other columns .. 
let's say in Col J2 .. you want the value for that row from col T:

```
=OFFSET(Assets!T1,I2-1,0,1,1)
```

Hope that helps!